# Gradient of dot product

Tags: vector-analysis

If $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ are two vectors such that $\vec A=<A_x,A_y,A_z>$ and $\vec B=<B_x,B_y,B_z>$ then

$$\nabla({\vec A}.{\vec B})=A \times (\nabla \times B)+B \times (\nabla \times A)+(A.\nabla)B+(B.\nabla)A$$

In this relation what does this $(A.\nabla)B$ imply? How does this work on vector? Isn't gradient meant to be operated on scalar function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [physical meaning of the vector $(A \cdot \nabla) A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232855/physical-meaning-of-the-vector-a-cdot-nabla-a) OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3285119/how-to-compute-mathbfa-cdot-mathbf-nabla-mathbfb?rq=1

Comment: see this link: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/232855/875207)
perhaps it might help you in your work...

Comment: Does totally differentiable with jacobian matrix mean that the first partial derivatives exist?

Comment: Total differentiability is stronger than that. But you can safely assume that functions you're confronted with in vector calculus are totally differentiable. The Jacobian is essentially a matrix with the gradients of the component functions as its rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $\vec A\cdot\nabla$ is the directional derivative operator in the direction $\vec A$. If you have some experience with analysis, you might know that if $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is totally differentiable with Jacobian $\mathrm Jf(x)$ in $x$, then all its directional derivatives exist and can be calculated as $\mathrm Jf(x)v$, where $v$ is the direction.

Sometimes this is also written as $(\nabla f)^T v$, using the nabla operator. We can write this as

$$(\nabla f)^Tv=(\partial_1 f)v_1+\dots+(\partial_n f)v_n.$$

Keep in mind that $\partial_i f$ are vector valued functions. This expression we could also write as $(v_1\partial_1+\dots+v_n\partial_n)f$. Formally, the expression in parentheses is just $v\cdot\nabla$, so we can write the whole thing as

$$(\nabla f)^T v=(v\cdot\nabla)f.$$

The takeaway is: $v\cdot\nabla$ is the directional derivative operator in direction $v$ because $(v\cdot\nabla)f=(\nabla f)^T v$, and the expression on the right side is known to give you the directional derivative.